# Jquery multi select

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

have this code:

```
 var firstname = $('#Passenger_FirstName');
 var lastName = $('#Passenger_LastName');

 $('#Passenger_FirstName,#Passenger_LastName').keyup(function () {});
```

I want to use it like this:

```
$(firstname,lastname).keyup(function () {});
```

but the selector does not seem to work correctly, any ideas?

Comment: When you pass 2 parameters to `$`, the 2nd is the "context".  `$(sel1, sel2)` is the same as `$(sel2).find(sel1)`.  Just FYI.

Answer (score 4):

You also can use `.add()`

```
firstname.add(lastName).keyup(function() {});
```